# Is it true that Ravana was invited when Rama established a Shiva Lingam in Rameshwaram?

Tags: shiva, ramayana, rama, ravana, valmiki

I keep hearing a story which follows as

> Rama needed a bridge to cross the ocean to reach Lanka, in order to
> defeat Ravana.
>
> He decided to conduct a Yagna to worship Lord Shiva at Rameshwaram.
>
> As he was going to fight one of his most powerful adversaries, he
> needed the most scholarly priest to conduct the Yagna.
>
> Rama was informed that only Ravana is the most scholarly priest of all
> time.
>
> Therefore Ravana was invited for pratishtapan of Shiva ling.

I wish to verify if this is true.